# WHM: Globally change Indexing to be None and request passwords via HTTP window

Tags: indexing

I am using WHM. I want to set the default behaviour for any created accounts to be No-Indexing.

Also, when an account accesses CPanel, I want it to be shown the HTTP prompt for user and password instead of the HTML form.

How can I do that please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part of your question

To disable indexing globally, go to:

Main >> Service Configuration >> Apache Configuration >> Global Configuration

And then you can deselect indexing and save and rebuild conf to disable it by default, alternatively you can create a skeleton .htaccess file in  /root/cpanel3-skel which the line

```
Options -Indexes
```

For the second part, the setting is in the security section of tweak settings in WHM:
Main >> Server Configuration >> Tweak Settings

```
Enable HTTP Authentication
```

However for security I would not recommend making this change

Comment: TO be sure: I need to deselect all of these: ExecCGI, FollowSymLinks, Includes, IncludesNOEXEC, Indexes, MultiViews, SymLinksIfOwnerMatch?

Comment: you only have to deselect indexes